# Can't format sd card bootmrg virus

Tags: sd-card

I can't format my SD Card I was try disk part, SD Formatter, Windows Disk manger But i cant format my SD card Its Showing 45 MB my card is 4Gb Tell me any other way to format It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps. First install Microsoft Security Essentials then install unlocker. Do a full scan and then run unlocker on the card connected to your computer, kill all process and then format it.

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: where is unlocker

Comment: I just found it on Cnet: http://download.cnet.com/archive/3000-2248_4-11570226.html#userReviews?v=1

Comment: it's unknown file